# Transform time spans to discrete steps

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel sheet of some jobs (or whatever items/action) and their start and end date.
Now for each minute of the day, I need to know how many jobs were active.

So the input looks like this:

```
Jobname |        Start        |         End          
---------------------------------------------------      
JobA    | 04/10/2015 08:00:00 | 04/10/2015 09:00:00
JobB    | 04/10/2015 10:00:00 | 04/10/2015 10:00:59
JobC    | 04/10/2015 10:00:00 | 04/10/2015 11:00:00
```

The output shall look like this:

**Note**: Jobnames just added for clearity, in the real output I am only interested in the number of active jobs per minute, not which jobs were active

```
Time                | Number of active jobs
---------------------------------------------------      
04/10/2015 00:00:00 | 0
[..]
04/10/2015 08:00:00 | 1 (JobA)
04/10/2015 08:01:00 | 1 (JobA)
[..]
04/10/2015 09:00:00 | 1 (JobA)
04/10/2015 09:01:00 | 0
[..]
04/10/2015 09:59:00 | 0
04/10/2015 10:00:00 | 2 (JobB, JobC)
04/10/2015 10:01:00 | 1 (JobC)
[..]
04/10/2015 11:00:00 | 1 (JobC)
04/10/2015 11:01:00 | 0
[..]
04/10/2015 23:59:00 | 0
```

Can anyone help me how this kind of data transformation can be done using Excel? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Number of active jobs**

You can count the number of rows using:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Start],"<="&[@Time],Table1[End],">="&[@Time])
```

The above formula works only when the data range is a **Table** (convert a range into a table by pressing `Ctrl+T`)  named `Table1` (rename by pressing `Alt, m, n`),  and your desired output range is also a Table.

If you do not convert ranges into tables, you shoulr make reference to ranges with `A1` for a cell or `B:B` for a whole column.

**Time**

The column contains the minutes. The first row is entered with the first minute that you want. In the subsequent rows, the minutes can be computed by adding a minute to the previous rows:

```
=A2+TIME(0,1,0)
```

*Remarks*

1. Using `COUNTIFS` can be extremely *slow*.
2. I'm not sure whether adding a minute accumulates **floating point errors** in *any* case.
3. If your data really looks like what you've typed (*delimited* with vertical bars), you might also need **Text to columns** `Alt, A, E`.